# Spark unpersist when cache() was never called

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm reviewing someone's code and I see they're calling `df.unpersist()` on a dataframe that was never cached. This is an abbreviated version of the code:

```
def get_and_prepare_data():
   # Read the data
   input_df = spark.sql('SELECT * FROM my_table')
   
   try:
      # Do a bunch of transformations, etc
      df = input_df.repartition(partition_ct)
      df = df.groupBy(order_id).agg(collect_list(item_id).alias("my_items"))
   
   except Exception as err:
      error_list.append(str(err))
      log_error(err)

   finally:
      df.unpersist()

   return df
```

Later, they pass along the df for use in other methods, like:

```
def join_and_filter(df):
   filtered = df.filter(...)
   filtered.count()
```

**Question 1: Does the "df.unpersist()" even do anything?** My understanding is that unpersist removes a dataframe from cache, and if it was never cached then there's nothing to remove. Are there any side effects of calling `unpersist` in this case?

**Question 2**, currently there is no Spark action in `get_and_prepare_data()`, so I'd think the `join_and_filter()` method would execute once for all the lazy steps leading up to it:

1. execute spark SQL query
2. repartition
3. group by / agg
4. unpersist
5. filter
6. count

If there was a `count()` action after the group by, I think the code would do the following:

JOB A:

1. execute spark SQL query
2. repartition
3. group by / agg
4. count

JOB B:

1. execute spark SQL query
2. repartition
3. group by / agg
4. unpersist
5. filter
6. count

In which case, the persist *still* wouldn't do anything (unless we add `.cache()` or `.persist`).
Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: 1. unpersist() in your current code doesn't have any effect.
2. Adding an action like count() after transformations will create separate Spark jobs, and without caching, the DataFrame will be recomputed for each job.